# awk same start and end pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a pattern as shown below. I am trying to extract a multiline record(from Dr Group Name to the first blank line). I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n" } /DR Group Name: \\Data Replication\\mc_wtec_1/,/\n/'
```

But it gets me all four records.

```
Storage WWN: 50001FE15007DBA0
    DR Group Name: \Data Replication\mc_wtec_1
        WWID list:
                   600508B4001078FD0002400001800000

    DR Group Name: \Data Replication\vanilla_dr
        WWID list:
                   600508B4001078F10002400002D20000


Storage WWN: 50001FE15007DBD0
    DR Group Name: \Data Replication\mc_wtec_1
        WWID list:
                   600508B4001078FD0002400001800000

    DR Group Name: \Data Replication\vanilla_dr
        WWID list:
                   600508B4001078F10002400002D20000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/wtec_1/ {ok=1} /^$/ {ok=0} {if(ok){print $0}}' filename
```

Does what you seem to have asked.  Based on the sample.

Answer (score 2):

The `RS="\n"` part is odd; isn't that the default record separator? Removing it makes no difference to the matched output, and I would not expect it to.

The end pattern is bogus too. You are searching for a line containing a newline, but `awk` removes the newlines from input lines, so it doesn't match anything, hence the pattern range extends from the first `DR Group Name` line to the end of the file.

You want to look for an empty line; that is `/^$/`.  Hence:

```
$ awk '/DR Group Name: \\Data Replication\\mc_wtec_1/,/^$/' data
    DR Group Name: \Data Replication\mc_wtec_1
        WWID list:
                   600508B4001078FD0002400001800000

    DR Group Name: \Data Replication\mc_wtec_1
        WWID list:
                   600508B4001078FD0002400001800000
$
```

Comment: Empty line search is a fine solution

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to remove the 'Storage WWN' lines and then you'll get each record:

```
< input sed '/^Storage WWN/d' | awk '{ print "Record: ", $0 }' RS=
```

For example, to get the third record:

```
< input sed '/^Storage WWN/d' | awk NR==3 RS=
```

To get the mc_wtec_1, try:

```
< input sed '/^Storage WWN/d' | awk '/mc_wtec_1/' RS=
```

(In all of the above, your input data is assumed to be in a file named 'input'.  That file can be specified as an argument to `sed` rather than redirected by the shell, and doing the redirection before 'sed' is not necessary.)

Comment: I can't help but feel it is a little clumsy to be using both `awk` and `sed` when `awk` alone will suffice.

Comment: @Jonathan, I agree, but I can't see a good way to remove individual lines along with a reassignment of RS.  This seems hackish, but acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Search for pattern and print two lines after it:

```
awk '/ DR Group Name: \Data Replication\mc_wtec_1/{print;for(i=1;i<=3;i++){getline;print}}' filename
```

**Or better way**,

add regular expression search pattern in script

```
awk '/ DR Group Name: \\Data Replication\\mc_wtec_1/,/([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/' filename
```

`([A-Z]+[0-9]+)` will look for `600508B4001078FD0002400001800000` pattern

**OUTPUT:**

```
DR Group Name: \Data Replication\mc_wtec_1
    WWID list:
               600508B4001078FD0002400001800000

DR Group Name: \Data Replication\mc_wtec_1
    WWID list:
               600508B4001078FD000240000180000000
```

Comment: That works with the sample data, but there is room to think that a `WWID list` might contain more than one line of data (otherwise, it isn't much of a list), at which point this becomes fragile.  The specification says the end of the record is marked by a blank line; a good solution will work with that rather than a line count.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes thanks that's true, added other alternative